# Form Last Name Length Check in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We have a form and we're trying to validate the entry of the last name field to make sure that, at a minimum, there is at least two characters entered. Here is the type of code we're using:

```
<cfif form.last_name is "S">
    <cfset errors = errors & "<li>You must include your <b>complete</b> last name.</li>">
</cfif>
```

Any thoughts on how we can make sure that the last name field has two or more letters (without doing each letter individually as a separate check, as above). Other thoughts on how to validate last names more effectively would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Len() function:

```
<cfif Len(FORM.last_name) GTE 2>
  <!--- perform success stuff here --->
</cfif>
```

The above code means "If the length of the last_name field submitted via http form post is 2 or more characters..."

Free tip: Be super-fancy and trim the field's whitespace before making the check:

```
<cfif Len(Trim(FORM.last_name)) GTE 2>
  <!--- perform success stuff here --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: You can get even more fancy with a regex check. To verify that there are two LETTERS (as opposed to numbers, special characters), use `<cfif Len(REReplace(FORM.last_name, "[^A-Za-z]", "", "ALL")) GTE 2>`